# ImportError using Squeezenet in Python

Tags: python, keras, importerror

I have been trying to get a tutorial working, that uses the keras_squeezenet package in Python. When I try to run one of the files, I get an ImportError. I have tried both adding a line to import keras, and to import keras_squeezenet at the top, but this hasn't fixed the problem. The full error message:

```
  File "train_model.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet.squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\squeezenet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\imagenet_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    backend = get_keras_submodule('backend')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\__init__.py", line 34, in get_keras_submodule
    raise ImportError('You need to first `import keras` '
ImportError: You need to first `import keras` in order to use `keras_applications`. For instance, you can do:

import keras
from keras_applications import vgg16

Or, preferably, this equivalent formulation:


from keras import applications
```

If anyone could please help me with this error, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you didn't install the relevant package well or you installed an old version of that package

uninstall the package and then reinstall it

Or

you can update it

Answer (score 0):

You need first to write the following before the line from keras_squeezenet:

```py
import keras 
from keras_applications import vgg16
```